# How to use Collection remove if his list meet a condition?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list with some `Person` Object. Here is my `Person` class:

```
public class Person(){
// contructors 

private String lastname;

private String firstname;

private List<Place> places;

// getters and setters
}
```

My `Place` class is :

```
public class Place(){
// contructors 

private String town;

// getters and setters
}
```

I have code to remove some places from person:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
// adding persons to List
// Below i want to remove person whose place is in town Paris.
persons.removeIf((Person person)-> person.getPlaces(???));
```

I want to remove a person from the list whose `Place` meets the following condition  `place.getTown()=="Paris"`

How to write this code?

Comment: Ask the person who wrote `removeIf...`

Comment: @RC. [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) is a standard method in Java

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know, my point was if you can write a removeIf you can answer the question

Comment: @RC. That is a rather circular argument, and not helpful at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a method *hasPlace* to Person class:

```
public boolean hasPlace(String townName) {
    return places.stream()
            .map(Place::getTown)
            .anyMatch(townName::equals);
}
```

Then, you can use this in the predicate given to the removeIf statement:

```
persons.removeIf(person -> person.hasPlace("Paris"));
```

Comment: Thank yo for your answer. I tried it but it just removes places from person and not the person which place is Paris. Am i miss something ?

Comment: What you say is not possible: this code will only READ places from a person, and shouldn't ouch anything. Maybe you can post your complete code to check?

Answer (score 6):

Stream over the list of `Places` to determine if it contains a `Place` whose `town` is "Paris":

```
persons.removeIf(p-> p.getPlaces().stream().anyMatch(pl->pl.getTown().equals("Paris")));
```

Comment: Why not do: collectionName.removeIf(x -> x.getName().equals(name_to_compare)); ?

Comment: @GCP Because the `Person` class doesn't contain the name you have to compare to "Paris". You have to check the `getPlaces()` list for instances of `Places` that contain the town "Paris".

Comment: I just noticed there is only one field in that class. My bad.

Comment: Thank yo for your answer. I tried it but it just removes places from person and not the person which place is Paris. Am i miss something ?

Comment: @Pracede `persons.removeIf()` can only remove `Person` instance from the `persons` `List`. It does not mutate the elements it removes, so what you describe is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use removeIf method, you could use Filter to

```
persons.stream().filter(p-> !p.getPlaces().stream().anyMatch(pl->pl.getTown().equals("Paris")));
```

Comment: You need to invert the filter, because now you get all the people which have a place `"paris"`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks. :)